The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]. It should be an element. Cannot capture Xpath for the text after :: (double colons)
I'm trying to capture "News & Events". But I can't get Xpath for the text after :: (double colons)
Please refer this image for the html code
private IWebElement newsAndEventsHeadding => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/text()"));

public string GetHeadding(){
      return newsAndEventsHeadding.Text;
}

[Test]
public void TestNewsAndEventsPage_Headding(){            
      Assert.AreEqual("News & Events", newsAndEventsPage.GetHeadding());
}

I tried the above code. But it gives the below error:
The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

@kjhughes This is not a good dup target for this question. The error message and the source of the problem are completely different than this one. I know this question has been asked at least several times before but that target is not one of them.

@JeffC: I believe the essence of OP's problem is how to "capture 'News & Events'", which is text in a pseudo element, which is addressed by the duplicate link.  The error message is a red herring because the wrong XPath is producing text, not an element.   In what way do you feel "the source of the problem" is completely different than that of how to select text in a pseudo element?

@kjhughes The error OP is getting is due to the XPath ending in text() which is not supported by Selenium. While the text is in a pseudo element, it doesn't really change anything from a locator perspective. I can't test their locator because we don't have the URL but my assumption is that if they just removed /text() from the locator it would work.

@JeffC: Again, the error is entirely incidental to OP's goal:  "I'm trying to capture 'News & Events'," which is stored in a pseudo element, which is inaccessible via XPath because pseudo elements are not in the DOM.
